# PDFBox Insert a PDF File as a Page into Another PDF file

Tags: java, pdfbox, smb

Using PDFBox within a java web app.
I have a PDF file that represents a multiple sheet drawing or blue print. There are other PDF files that represent amendments to the parent file. I would like to insert these pages into the parent PDF file between page 1 and page 2.

I have found articles on merging and adding pages but not quite what I need here.

Some direction would be very helpful.

My code so far:

```
try{

                InputStream in = null;
                OutputStream out = null;
                PDDocument document = null;

                String parentfile = "";
                for(DLDrawingFile dldf: dldwg.getDldrawingfileList()){
                    System.out.println("DocsVisionDrawingList: AcrobatRotateAndMerge_3: " + dldf.getDrawingnumber() + " " + dldf.getTypeID());

                    if(parentfile.equals("") && dldf.getTypeID().equals("DRAWING")){

                        NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(attachmentRoot_DOMAIN,attachmentRoot_ID,attachmentRoot_PW);

                        SmbFile file = new SmbFile("smb:" + dldf.getDldrawingfile(), auth);
                        file.connect();

                        File file2 = new File(dldf.getDldrawingfile()); 

                        in = new BufferedInputStream(new SmbFileInputStream(file));

                        document = PDDocument.load(in);

                        parentfile = dldf.getDldrawingfile();
                        System.out.println("DocsVisionDrawingList: AcrobatRotateAndMerge_3: Parent: " + parentfile);
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("DocsVisionDrawingList: AcrobatRotateAndMerge_3: Child: " + dldf.getDldrawingfile());
                        //this is where the child files would be iterated over.

                    }
                }

            }
            catch(Exception e){

            }
```

Comment: Did you try `PDPageTree.insertBefore(PDPage newPage, PDPage nextPage)`?

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING**
A good beginner solution. However, in the comment below, MLK mentions **it is incomplete.** Another problem with this method is that it only works if its the last bit of code because it closes the COSStream which would prevent you from adding any future text

I know this is old post, but here is the anwser that worked for me if anyone else experiences the same problem. Tilman Hausherr's method worked for me

```
PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
for (int numberOfPages = 0; numberOfPages < 10; numberOfPages++) {
            //Creating a blank page
            PDPage blankPage = new PDPage();
            //Adding the blank page to the document
            document.addPage(blankPage);
        }
PDPageTree mergePD = document.getPages();
PDDocument doc1 = PDDocument.load(file1);
PDDocument doc2 = PDDocument.load(file2);



//the left argument is the page number of the pdf that is being inserted
   //the right argument is the page number of the original pdf that places the inserted pdf

mergePD.insertAfter(doc1.getPage(0),document.getPage(0)); //creates a new page after page 0
mergePD.insertAfter(doc2.getPage(0),document.getPage(1)); //creates a new page after page 1
```

Comment: while this works somehow, it is an incomplete solution, in particular if the source pages contain form fields or tagged content as neither the target document AcroForm information nor its structure tree are updated.

Comment: @mkl You are right. I updated the post to give a warning. I am thinking to still keep this up as the tutorials are rare and have a steep learning curve. Do you agree?